# Textarea inline with multiple rows in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, textarea

I'm trying to come up with a template that looks like the following:

```
 Label  Input               Label   Input
 Label  Input               Label   Input
 Label  Textarea            Label   Input
        Textarea (cont.)    Label   Input
```

I can't seem to figure out which way to do this with bootstrap at the moment.

Here's what I currently have (on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tj2N/3/)):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">Label 1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text" value="" maxlength="50"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">Label 2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input id="input2" name="input2" type="text" value="" maxlength="50"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">Label 3</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input id="input3" name="input3" type="text" value="" maxlength="50"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">Label 4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input id="input4" name="input4" type="text" value="" maxlength="50"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">Label 5</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea" rows="5" cols="17"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">Label 6</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input id="input6" name="input6" type="text" value="" maxlength="50"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-1">Label 7</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input id="input7" name="input7" type="text" value="" maxlength="50"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This produces something that looks like this:

```
 Label  Input               Label   Input
 Label  Input               Label   Input
 Label  Textarea            Label   Input
        Textarea (cont.)
                            Label   Input
```

Obviously the issue is me placing the textarea in the row, but I can't figure out where else to put it for my desired output.

Any ideas?

Comment: So next you need to move your last label and input into the same row as the textarea, but same column as your other inputs.

Comment: That's correct, but the issue here is I can't seem to find an offset that works correctly.

**Edit**: I noticed a copy/paste error on my part with the current result. Fixed.

Comment: I don't think you went about the format correctly, I will see if I can help shortly and make a bootply.

Comment: [So there's this option](http://jsfiddle.net/9tj2N/4/). But it means the breakpoints don't work correctly unfortunately, and the row heights aren't uniform, albeit that's trivial... just makes me think there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it to how I was expecting it to work, and am pretty sure this is the *correct* answer to the question I asked.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tj2N/6/).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">Label 1</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text" value="" maxlength="50"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">Label 3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input id="input3" name="input3" type="text" value="" maxlength="50"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">Label 2</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input id="input2" name="input2" type="text" value="" maxlength="50"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">Label 4</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input id="input4" name="input4" type="text" value="" maxlength="50"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">Label 5</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea" rows="5" cols="17"></textarea>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">Label 6</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input id="input6" name="input6" type="text" value="" maxlength="50"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">Label 7</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input id="input7" name="input7" type="text" value="" maxlength="50"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the formatting I used in this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Z0H6UWnuJ0).

**Code:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1">
    <div>Label</div>
    <div>Label</div>
    <div>Label</div>
</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
    <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text" value="" maxlength="50">
    <input id="input2" name="input2" type="text" value="" maxlength="50">
    <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea" rows="5" cols="17"></textarea>
</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1">
    <div>Label</div>
    <div>Label</div>
    <div>Label</div>
    <div>Label</div>
</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
    <input id="input3" name="input3" type="text" value="" maxlength="50">
    <input id="input4" name="input4" type="text" value="" maxlength="50">
    <input id="input5" name="input5" type="text" value="" maxlength="50">
    <input id="input6" name="input6" type="text" value="" maxlength="50">
</div>
```

I broke up the labels and inputs into 4 columns, you might need some extra CSS to line the labels up a little better but this fixes your gap issue.

[image]